# Get All aspx-files using a specific Master-page

Tags: asp.net, reflection

I'm trying to get the path for all the .aspx-files that has a specific MasterPageFile value.

Lets say I have a aspx-file called "hi.aspx" with the MasterPageFile="hello.Master" in the page directive. I want to get the value from the MasterPageFile property through reflection, in a method like so:

```
GetAllASpxFilesUsingMasterFile("~/hello.Master"); 
> hi.aspx
```

The problem Im having using:

```
var type = BuildManager.GetCompiledType(path)
Activator.CreateInstance(type)
```

is that the MasterPageFile-property is null.. ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have just called the constructor and created a new instance that´s why MasterPageFileProperty is null. There is no page life cycle involved which is necessary for populating pages with controls and properties.

To get the actual page life cycle process going you should call ProcessRequest() method but this is not advised at all.

```
        Type type = BuildManager.GetCompiledType("~/Default.aspx");

        Page myPage = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        myPage.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);
```